# `required` property and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, required, ef-core-3.1, c#-11.0

One year ago, in C# ver. 11, modifier `required` was added. So, if we mark property as required like below:

```
public class Point
{
    public required int X { get; set; }
    public required int Y { get; set; }
}
```

we can't create `Point` instance without init X and Y, so if we try:

```
        Point fake = new Point();
```

we get an compiler error:

> Required member 'Point.X' must be set in the object initializer or
> attribute constructor.
> Required member 'Point.Y' must be set in the
> object initializer or attribute constructor.

and the following code is ok:

```
Point point = new() { X = 1, Y = 2 };
```

Usually, this feature is necessary for parsing JSON (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/required-properties))

Ok. But let's look at EF Core. If we create entity model like this:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
}
```

we get a warning:

> Non-nullable property 'FolderName' must contain a non-null value when
> exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

but if we mark it as `required`:

```
public class DownloadCenterFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FolderName { get; set; }
}
```

warning is disappeared

So, is it a good way to use `required` keyword for mandatory fields (which marked as `builder.Property(p => p.ProjectName).IsRequired();`) when we use EF Core or not? It looks like pretty (first at all, to avoid init this field by empty string in ctor) and I can't find anything in google about using this keyword with EF Core. Or, probably, any other way to mark mandatory fields?

Thanks

Comment: Since v7, EFCore supports calling constructors directly from within an `IQueryable<T>.Select` now, FWIW - so you could do that if you have a type with `required` properties that you can't set externally - (fwiw, I never liked the concept of `required` properties: I don't see how it's any improvement over traditional constructors...)

Comment: The EF concept of `IsRequired` has different semantics to C#'s `required` -properties - they're sufficiently different such that I don't think it's appropriate to treat them as equivalent. Also, EF allows the _very definition_ of "IsRequired" to be defined by your RDBMS (or application-defined `CHECK` constraints) - whereas `required` properties cannot. And don't confuse it with `[RequiredAttribute]` either.

Comment: @Dai I did not mean, that EF `IsRequired` is equal of C# keyword `required`, I just focused on the field is mandatory and not nullable :)

Comment: I think the point of the question is whether it's appropriate to use required keyword as a workaround to the annoying compiler warnings.